# Erro com dados mysqli e Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Estou com um problema ao buscar dados usando ajax.

```
<script>
//função buscar dados
    function buscarDados(id) {
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/dados_aluno.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id: id},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#visualizar_aluno').html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Ocorreu um erro com o AJAX');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
</script>
```

com esse codigo eu pego os dados no mysqli com php.

```
<?php

require_once '../../../config/config.php';

//pegar id do aluno
$id = $_POST['id'];

//fazer busca no banco de dados
$sql = "SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE id=$id";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$nome = $row['nome'];
$obs = $row['obs'];

echo "<script>$('#nome').html('$nome');$('#obs').html('$obs');</script>";
```

porém isso da erro ao enviar os dados da variável obs que são dados com quebra de linha ex: 
"oi eu sou nub,
e queria
saber"
ele retorna assim ao realizar a ação (deixando claro que apenas o nome funciona perfeitamente, só quando há quebra de linha que para de funcionar)

```
<script>
$('#nome').html('Fulano de Tal');
$('#obs').html('Os dados
estão
quebrados')
</script>
```

ai da erro e não sei resolver

Comment: Tente trocar por ` veja sobre templates literais https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals, então coloque assim  $('#obs').html(`Os dados
estão
quebrados`)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado

Comment: Tudo bem, postarei como resposta então beleza? Ai você aceita. Obrigado

Comment: Coloque que aceito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver isso você pode utilizar o template literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals adicionado no ecma script 2016. Ficando da seguinte forma

```
<script>
$('#nome').html('Fulano de Tal');
$('#obs').html(`Os dados
estão
quebrados`)
</script>
```

Você pode também caso seja de sua preferencia, adicionar quebras de linhas e concatenar com o "+", ficando assim

```
<script>
$('#nome').html('Fulano de Tal');
$('#obs').html('Os dados\n' + 
'estão
quebrados')
</script>
```